# less ParseError: Missing closing ')'

Tags: less

I am currently working on an template using less and I have encountered an unusual error:

> less ParseError: Missing closing ')'.

This is the code where the error occured:

```
less.modifyVars({
  '@buttonFace': '#5B83AD',
  '@buttonText': '#D9EEF2'
});
```

I am sure I correctly used the closing ')' but the error says I didn't.
please help.

Comment: Are you using SimpLESS?

Comment: You posted your JavaScript code which is correct actually. But your error is raised from your Less code. (Or are your trying to use `modifyVars` function in Less source code itself? This is wrong of course).

Answer (score 0):

```
 less.modifyVars({
  '@buttonFace': '#5B83AD',
  '@buttonText': '#D9EEF2'
});
```

I have a doubt, why do you have to use '' for variable and its value.

```
less.modifyVars({
  @buttonFace: #5B83AD,
  @buttonText: #D9EEF2
});
```

if the variable @buttonFace is a property, you are making it a string by using single quotes.

for example:

```
.mixin(@property, @value){
    @{property}:@value;
}

.blackButton{.mixin(background,#ccc);.mixin(color,white);}

.rule(@className;@rules){
    .@{className}{
       @rules();
    }
}

.rule(blackButton;{
    .mixin(background,black);
    .mixin(color,white);
});
```

or else could you please elaborate on your problem. All I see in your code is string : string;

Comment: well you see, I am using less for the first time after following the steps in the documentation on this site:http://lesscss.org/#client-side-usage 

all the code together is a bit much but it should be working. If you want to see it i can show you all of the code.

Comment: No not all of the code, I just wanted to know what you want to execute.

Comment: I have discovered that when i put my code in the online LESS compiler (http://winless.org/online-less-compiler) it gives the error:Unrecognised input

while when running the code it says: ParseError: Missing closing ')'

when running the code it always gives the same error even when the code is removed or altered.

Comment: I have (kind of) fixed the problem by deviding the less.modifyVars statement in two, not 
less.modifyVars({
  'abuttonFace': '#5B83AD',
  'abuttonText': '#D9EEF2'
});

but like this:

less.modifyVars{
  @buttonFace: '#5B83AD',
};

less.modifyVars{
 abuttonText: '#D9EEF2'
};

however this has created a new problem.

it says here: .text-muted {
 color: ablue;
}
that the variable ablue is undefined.

NOTE: I used a instead of the token that points out that the following word will be a variable beceause @ can only be used once in a comment

Comment: @jess19 Notice my comment above - `modifyVars` is *JavaScript* function - obviously *Less* compiler cannot understand JavaScript code. So you're better to elaborate on what you're trying to achieve overall. If you're just about setting Less variable value, the syntax is just [`@var: value;`](http://lesscss.org/features/#features-overview-feature-variables).